# Removing JSON level heirarchy from a structure class

Tags: java, json

Is it possible to remove the level hierarchy on the resulting JSON string wherein the Java class structure is final (see `Class Definition` below)? Currently, the abstract result of a populated `Root` class is shown on *JSON_ACTUAL* but I'm expecting a *JSON_EXPECTED_OUTPUT* as a JSON response without restructuring the class definition.

**Class Definition**

```
@XmlRootElement("json")
@XMLAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Root {
    @XMLElement(name="keyOne")
    String keyOne;

    @XMLElement(name="childOne") 
    ChildOne childOne;

    @XMLElement(name="childTwo") 
    ChildTwo childTwo;

    // Possible more child.
    // Child can have its own child property(ies)
}

@XmlRootElement
class ChildOne {
    @XMLElement(name="keyTwo")
    String keyTwo;

    @XMLElement(name="keyThree")
    String keyThree;
}

@XmlRootElement
class ChildTwo {
    @XMLElement(name="keyFour")
    String keyFour;

    @XMLElement(name="keyFive")
    List<ChildThree> keyFive;
}
```

**JSON_ACTUAL**

```
"json": {
    "keyOne": <valueFor_keyOne>,
    "childOne": {
        "keyTwo": <valueFor_keyTwo>,
        "keyThree": <valueFor_keyThree>
    }
}
```

**JSON_EXPECTED_OUTPUT**

```
"json": {
    "keyOne": <value_for_keyOne>,
    "keyTwo": <value_for_keyTwo>,
    "keyThree": <value_for_keyThree>,
    "keyFive": [<elementList_for_keyFive>]
}
```

Any hints on how to produce **JSON_EXPECTED_OUTPUT** from a Java class structure of **Class Definition**?

---

EDIT:

- Having multiple child properties on root
- Child may contain it's own child class property(ies)
- Property can be a collection or array.

Answer (score 0):

For that you should extend that class

```
@XmlRootElement("json")
@XMLAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Root extends ChildOne {
    @XMLElement(name="keyOne")
    String keyOne;

}
```

So that all the fields in various class are included in your current instance.

Comment: Would it be the same structure if I have another or multiple child class. Also the child class has it's own child class in it? See edited version above.